# Pandas DataFrame types not being set automatically

Tags: python, pandas, decimal

I'm trying to create a Pandas DataFrame from some text data which I'm iterating over (it's a dump of lots of json strings from an API).

Some of the data is small numbers, eg `0.00000001`. I'm using the Python Decimal type for these elsewhere in another app. I'm not sure how to get Pandas to recognise that these are decimals. Whether I create Decimal objects from them first, or create a DataFrame just from the strings, Pandas creates generic `object` columns. There are other columns which are different formats.

To take a simple example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([Decimal('0.01'),])
df.dtypes
```

Outputs:

```
0    object
dtype: object
```

Should I be using the Decimal type? Am I fundamentally misunderstanding something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need `type` for check `Decimal`:

```
from decimal import Decimal
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([Decimal('0.01'),])
print (df)
      0
0  0.01

print (type(df.loc[0, 0]))
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

`pandas` recognise only some `dtypes` like `int`, `float` ..., all others are `object`s (`string`s, `list`s, `Decimal`s).

I think you can check [relative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43992862/2901002) answer.

Comment: Ah so it's a non issue. I could have been banging my head against that all day - thanks loads for your help!

Comment: Glad can help. Nice weekend!